# Proving that $x^2$ is not unifromly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Assuming $\delta > 0$, let $x_1 = \frac{1}{\delta}, x_2 = x_1 + \frac{\delta}{2}$.
Thus: 
$$|x_1 - x_2| = \frac{\delta}{2} \lt \delta$$
Since I am struggling to prove that $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, having any $\epsilon \gt 0$, following requirement has to be met:
$$|x_1^2 - x_2^2| \lt \epsilon$$
As such:
$|\frac{1}{\delta^2} - \frac{1}{\delta^2} + \frac{2\delta}{2\delta} + \frac{\delta^2}{4}| = |1 + \frac{\delta^2}{4}| \not \lt \epsilon$ when $\epsilon \lt 1$.

Question: is this proof valid? Since I discovered 1 as a **constant**, obviously independent from the $\delta$ change, there is infinite sequence of possible $\epsilon: 0 \lt \epsilon \le 1$ for which the uniform continuity requirement on the top is not completed? Seems to be enough for me.

Comment: What means 'uniformly discontinuous' ?

Comment: I think he means "not uniformly continuous."

Comment: Yeah, "not uniformly continuous".

Comment: Yes I suppose but I think it is very strange.

Comment: @Lucas the proof is strange?

Comment: The term uniformly discontinuous is strange. It sounds like the function is discontinuous and the discontinuity is uniform.

Comment: The idea of the proof is correct, but instead of saying "there are infinite sequence of possible..." all you need is that there exists some $\epsilon$ such that there exists some $x_1$ and $x_2$ which satisfy $|x_1 - x_2| < \delta$ but $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| > \epsilon.$ So just choose $\epsilon =1$ and be done with it.

Comment: I feel that "unifromly" is a lovely addition to English, while "unifrom" sounds a bit like "politically correct" but not too bad.

Comment: The proof is ok. I feel it is more natural to use sequences, but anyway it is ok.

Comment: @Jbag1212 according to the proof, whatever positive $\delta$ you pick, it won't work for $0 \lt \epsilon \le 1$.

Comment: And the 2nd question is: while $\epsilon$ keeps to be $\gt 1$, the requirement could be fulfilled. So is $x^2$ "partially" uniformly continuous there?..

Comment: Select $\ \epsilon = 1 $. Given a $\ \delta>0\ $, look for large arguments $\ x'\ x''\ $ (large enough but close one to another) to invalidate the delta constrain.

Comment: Sergei, you already have your proof (but for a tiny inessential computational error or similar). Just say for the sake of destroying uniformity: "Let $\ \epsilon=1".\ $ Then follow with your proof.

Comment: @WlodAA так идея-то в том, что при $\epsilon \gt 1$ функция как бэ равномерно непрерывна. Получается, если в моем конкретном  случае по не важно какой причине важны именно $\gt 1$ значения, то $x^2$ будет равномерно непрерывной на всем множестве действительных чисел. Хоп-хэй-ла-ла-лэй!

Comment: To prove that a function is not uniformly continuous, it's enough to present only ONE "wrong" $\ epsilon.\ $ It just happens that the given example of $\ f(x):=x^2\ $ is special in the sense that every $\ \epsilon>0\ $ would destroy uniformity. In the harder SPECIFIC cases you need to select that special $\ \epsilon\ $ pretty small, sometimes $\ 0.01,\ $ sometimes $\ 0.00001$, etc. However, once one $\ \epsilon\ $ destroys uniformity then every positive $\ \epsilon'<\epsilon\ $ would destroy it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f: D \to R$ is uniformly continuous if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in D$, $|x-y|< \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon.$

Let's put this into quantifiers,
$$\forall(\epsilon >0) \exists(\delta >0) \forall(x \in D) \forall(y \in D)\Big[|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon\Big].$$

So to be ``not uniformly continuous'' means

$$\exists(\epsilon >0) \forall(\delta >0) \exists(x \in D) \exists(y \in D)\Big[|x-y| < \delta \text{ and } |f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon\Big].$$

So you showed that
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |1+\frac{\delta^2}{4}| \geq \epsilon$$
for any $\epsilon \leq 1.$ So just choose $\epsilon =1.$

Comment: I guess there is a mistype: $\exists(\epsilon >0) \forall(\delta >0) \exists(x \in D) \exists(y \in D)\Big[|x-y| < \delta \text{ and } \delta  |f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon\Big]$. $ \delta  |f(x) - f(y)|$ shouldn't convey $\delta$ at the front.

Comment: I edited it to correct for that, thanks!

Comment: @Jbag1212, a nice decent answer. What was your "sin" since at this moment you have under 100 of the so-called reputation points?

Comment: @Jbag1212, wow, instead of $\ 99+10=109,\ $ right now you have "only" $\ 105\ $ points. You must be a "bad boy".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other aproach using sequences.

Take $$x_n=n+\frac {1}{n} $$
and
$$y_n=n .$$

thus
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|x_n-y_n|=0$$

but
$$x_n^2-y_n^2=2+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|x_n^2-y_n^2|=2\neq 0.$$

Comment: @WlodAA Okay. i did what you said. thnx.

Comment: You have presented the Heine's style (as opposed to Cauchy's style). Was there another name which historically goes with Heine, like Heine-Xxxxxx ?

Comment: Of the two equivalent styles (never mind axiom of choice one way or another), by Cauchy and by Heine, it's more natural to apply Cauchy in the positive statements, and it's more natural to apply Heine in the negative statements--then you provide so-to-speak the counter-example sequences without undue extra talking. (The above Answer supports my general observation).